# Tomcat Server Error

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting following error while starting my application:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CSRF
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

Tried to find jar for `org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter` on `findjar.com` but could not find anything.

Comment: Did it start up with a different Tomcat?  What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Did you declare any filter on web.xml?

Comment: generally speaking tomcat is loaded with classpath, make sure the jar file for this class is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should check your tomcat installation, since this is a tomcat class.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter

Comment: Yeah. I will do that. Recently I removed few transaction framework jars from Tomcat installation.